# Is it possbile for photons to pass through a non transparent object/fabric

Tags: photons

Would it be possible for a light photon to be able to pass though a sort of fabric like it would through glass but the the fabric would not be transparent.

So it would be like a window where only light comes through, but you wouldn't be able to see through it as if it was like a cement wall.

Comment: who do you define *transparent*? in general it means that light can pass through it... Also, how can light pass through something but you cannot see through it?  Sorry, the question doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Do you mean translucent?

Comment: You need to reword the question.
You can block visible light, but allow all non-visible light to pass. This will achieve a similar effect.
You can make light take a diversion using lenses and/or mirrors - (all light passes, but non "through" the window).

Comment: A material that light passes through, but you cannot see through it.  Can you tell us what you would do with this material?  That may help us understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At the quantum level it's not that simple. Opaque material is material dense enough to reflect most of the light back, there will invariably be some space where photons will squeeze through. Since it's such a small amount of photons our eyes can't detect them. With something like a cement wall, it's structure is so dense it becomes increasingly unlikely that a photon is able to get all the way through. With an opaque fabric photons will likely get through it just won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricting the photon to the visible spectrum, then no. However, if you refer to very low energy light such as radio, then it is possible for photons to pass through visibly opaque materials.

This is due to a quantum phenomenon (called a **band gap**), and is somewhat explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_and_indirect_band_gaps#Implications_for_light_absorption).

Answer (score 0):

Due to light's wave like properties it can move around opaque materials like the threads in material, so in that sense it came go through, actually around opaque materials.